# "Mage registry key "solarium_search_result" already exists"

Tags: magento-1.9, solr

I am trying to integrate Magento Community Edition v1.9.3.8 with SOLR (using this extension https://github.com/jeroenvermeulen/magento-solarium

I have successfully enabled Solarium in Magento and it connects with my solr server.

Doing a search in my frontend shows Products as Autocomplete correctly.

But if i press enter in the search field in order to go to the search results page, I get the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:57:"Mage registry key "solarium_search_result" already 
exists";i:1;s:7665:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/community/JeroenVermeulen/Solarium/Model/Resource/CatalogSearch/Fulltext.php(82): Mage::register('solarium_search...', Object(JeroenVermeulen_Solarium_Model_SearchResult))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(136): JeroenVermeulen_Solarium_Model_Resource_CatalogSearch_Fulltext->prepareResult(Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext), 's9', Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php(147): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->prepareResult()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php(126): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection->getFoundIds()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php(113): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection->_applySearchFilters()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/local/Itactica/LayeredNavigation/Model/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Category.php(72): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection->getSize()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(151): Itactica_LayeredNavigation_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Category->_getItemsData()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initItems()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(218): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(233): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->canShowOptions()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Layer.php(90): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->canShowBlock()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/design/frontend/intenso/default/template/itactica_layerednavigation/catalog/layer/view.phtml(18): Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer->canShowBlock()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#16 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/intens...')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('catalogsearch.l...', true)
#21 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/design/frontend/intenso/default/template/itactica_layerednavigation/catalog/product/list.phtml(60): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('catalogsearch.l...')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#23 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/intens...')
#24 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('search_result_l...', true)
#28 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php(161): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('search_result_l...')
#29 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/design/frontend/intenso/default/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml(26): Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result->getProductListHtml()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#31 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/intens...')
#32 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#33 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#34 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#36 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#38 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/design/frontend/intenso/default/template/page/1column.phtml(29): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#39 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#40 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/intens...')
#41 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#42 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#43 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#44 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#45 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/local/Itactica/LayeredNavigation/controllers/ResultController.php(155): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#46 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Itactica_LayeredNavigation_ResultController->indexAction()
#47 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#48 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#49 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#50 /var/www/vhosts/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#51 /var/www/vhosts/html/index.php(83): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#52 {main}";s:3:"url";s:94:"/catalogsearch/result/index/?model=samsung-galaxy-s9-g960f%2Csamsung-galaxy-s9-plus-g965f&q=s9";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: I have already cleared cache and turned compilation on and off...

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by placing `Mage::unregister('solarium_search_result');` just before the `Mage::register( 'solarium_search_result', $searchResult );`line

I dont know if it is a bad solution, but everything seems to work fine.

Comment: You could go to `Mage.php` and print the stack traces to see when is the first time the `solarium_search_result` registry entry is being set. Your solution is not bad, so to speak. But you never know, maybe the first time where it was being set was for something useful and you just unregistered it